# Javascript animation to multiple links?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want that the animation i did on first link should appear on all links. However i can apply id="tag" on only one of the links (see HTML code). I need a way so that same function can animate any link that calls it on mouse over.
Any alternate method will also do, maybe using 'this' keyword.

```js
function step(delta) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("tab");
  var from = [0, 0, 0],
    to = [180, 120, 120];
  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' +
    parseInt(from[0] + delta * (to[0] - from[0])) + ',' +
    parseInt(from[1] + delta * (to[1] - from[1])) + ',' +
    parseInt(from[2] + delta * (to[2] - from[2])) + ')';
}

function smooth() {
  var duration = 200;
  var start = new Date();
  var id = setInterval(change, 1);

  function change() {
    var timePassed = new Date() - start;
    var progress = timePassed / duration;
    if (progress > 1) progress = 1;
    var delta = progress;
    step(delta);
    if (progress == 1) clearInterval(id);
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styleweb.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="tab" onmouseover="smooth()" href="som.html">Shadow of Mordor</a></li>
    <li><a onmouseover="smooth()" href="tr.html">Tomb Raider</a></li>
    <li><a onmouseover="smooth()" href="ac.html">Assassin's Creed</a></li>
    <li><a onmouseover="smooth()" href="bf4.html">Battlefield 4</a></li>
  </ul>

</html>
```

Comment: Basically you want ```step()``` to be called as well, ```onmouseover```, right?

Comment: actually smooth() calls step(), so i want smooth() to be called onmouseover on all links

Comment: we would really appreciate it if you marked the answer that you found was the best solution to your problem as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

Important points:-

1) Have set a class of "tab" to the `li` elements instead of the anchor elements.

2) The `mouseover` event listeners are set for all "tab"-classed elements in the JS code, making your HTML neater.

3) Used `event.target` to pass the reference to the element on which the mouse hovered to `step()`

4) Would recommend adding another event listener for `mouseout` to reset the background color change for the li elements.

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34tbw2eh/3/)

Full Code =>

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            margin: 10px;
            width: 270px;
            float: left;
            opacity: 0.4;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        div a img:hover {
            opacity: 1.0;
            width: 290px;
            margin: 5px 0 0 0;
        }

        #mid {
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 40px auto;
            width: 1170px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="tab"><a href="som.html">Shadow of Mordor</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="tr.html">Tomb Raider</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="ac.html">Assassin's Creed</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="bf4.html">Battlefield 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mid">
        <div>
            <a href="http://worldversus.com/img/assassins-creed.jpg">
                <img src="images/ac/1.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.mediastinger.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Assassins-Creed-Black-Flag-after-credits-hq.jpg">
                <img src="images/ac/2.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="http://egmr.net/wp-content/gallery/18-nov-2014-review-ac-unity/assass-unity.jpg?24e25d">
                <img src="images/ac/3.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="https://images-eds-ssl.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTc0FCED4ph6ouevcPKpUexEae42sK1L4abdr36cYbFg4G4ofQlf6Ap41qwSQE4bCej.ENDwdWBb6xDzigKhhH0qYvtoqHqiprHkhGpbyYtNJE3oju9YrHyPXal_7gB.XZvNrsFG5dcIRXfUV33KDFrPeFl379b5KBjp2MNGhf.7LU-&format=jpg">
                <img src="images/ac/4.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mid">
        <div>
            <a href="http://hq-oboi.ru/photo/assasins_krid_1920x1080.jpg">
                <img src="images/ac/5.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.imgbase.info/images/safe-wallpapers/video_games/assassins_creed_2/4247_video_games_assasins_creed.jpg">
                <img src="images/ac/6.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="http://wallpoper.com/images/00/45/05/97/assassins-creed-11_00450597.jpg">
                <img src="images/ac/7.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="https://images-eds-ssl.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcsPTaZHCOi.gQ4NDogeo4.TqXBFvO.nSfIzhmc_YrTHs0al36bdFgkybp_1BaryxmOBZ4OnePryCoo0dAUhCvuKYPS17rz27TOZ6fKbVR9T9cW6h_VpeaE3eGtS8JmETueVQdOrvbOyLjTTbxjs_FKOhnSrdWbfQ2uFgJamJ929Y-&format=jpg">
                <img src="images/ac/8.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function step(delta, element) {
            console.log("step() called");
            var from = [0, 0, 0],
                to = [180, 120, 120];
            element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' +
                parseInt(from[0] + delta * (to[0] - from[0])) + ',' +
                parseInt(from[1] + delta * (to[1] - from[1])) + ',' +
                parseInt(from[2] + delta * (to[2] - from[2])) + ')';
        }

        function smooth(event) {
            console.log("smooth() called");
            var duration = 200;
            var start = new Date();
            var id = setInterval(change, 1);

            function change() {
                var timePassed = new Date() - start;
                var progress = timePassed / duration;
                if (progress > 1) progress = 1;
                var delta = progress;
                step(delta, event.target);
                if (progress == 1) clearInterval(id);
            }
        }

        var tabAnchorTags = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

        for (var i = 0; i < tabAnchorTags.length; i++) {
            tabAnchorTags[i].addEventListener("mouseover", smooth, false);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can u pls explain what happened here - 
for (var i = 0; i < tabAnchorTags.length; i++) {
            tabAnchorTags[i].addEventListener("mouseover", smooth, false);
        }

Comment: @DhruvChadha tabAnchorTags is an array of the HTML elements that have the class "tab". So I go through the array, and set the "mouseover" event listener for each of them. That's pretty much it. Its the same as setting ```onmouseover=smooth()``` in your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `class="tab"` on the `<a>` links. Then change this line `var elem = document.getElementById("tab");` to `var elem = document.getElementByClassName("tab");`

Comment: tried but doesnt work, wont this make elem an array of objects. I want that whichever <a> link calls smooth(), it should run for that link only......you know, as in many navigation panels

Answer (score 0):

Your smooth function can not be reached. Use JQUERY for your purpose.

You can assign one class name to each of your links and then write a jquery code to call that function instead of using onmouseover() event. if you use "tab" as your class name then your code shall be something like..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".tab").hover(function(){
       smooth(this);
   });
});
```

Here "this" becomes your element and hence you keep passing it till the last function where you actually change the rgba of the elements..

Moreover you can declare your variables outside the scope. This would not keep those variables unreachable hence undefined. So that's how you shall solve your problem.